# Value observers do not communicate correctly

Tags: swift, memory-management, closures, uitapgesturerecognizer, observers

Tap gesture get triggered by the below function;

```
@objc func handleTapGR(tapGR: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tapLocation = tapGR.location(in: nil)
        let moveNext = tapLocation.x > frame.width / 2 ? true : false

        moveNext ? userCards.nextImage() : userCards.previousImage()
    }
```

*UserCardViewModel:*

```
...        
    var imageIndex: Int = 0 { didSet{ imageIndexObserver?(imageIndex, userImages[imageIndex]) } }

    var imageIndexObserver: ((Int, UIImage) -> () )?
    mutating func nextImage() {
        imageIndex = imageIndex + 1 >= userImages.count ? 0 : imageIndex + 1
    }

    mutating func previousImage() {
        imageIndex = imageIndex - 1 < 0 ? userImages.count - 1  : imageIndex - 1
    }
```

Related closure needs to be triggered when the index is changed.
Below object is in related view.

```
var userCards: UserCardViewModel! {
        didSet{
            userCards.imageIndexObserver = { index, image in
                self.showingImage.image = self.userCards.userImages[index]
                print(index)                
           }
        }
    }
```

I am not able to get printed above the index statement at the first two taps.When I press right side on image (related array count is 2)

- At first tap; nothing happens.
- At second tap; prints 0.
- At third, it prints index = 1.

I am initializing like that (from related viewcontroller)

```
convenience init(userCards: UserCardViewModel) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        self.userCards = userCards
        configure()
    }
```

Comment: you want  to increase `imageIndex` on right tap and decrease on left tap...Right??

Comment: Tap gesture works fine, just value observers not communicate correctly.

Comment: Yeah, as i am checking it working totally fine.. like first time the initial value of imageIndex is 0. if tap on right it will become 1 and first time if i tap on left side the value become 3 ( i.e. yourArray.count - 1)....So can you tell me what output you are expecting?

Comment: lets say userImages.count = 2 and I tapped right corner. I am expecting to get index=2
but print function does not work.

Comment: if your array count is 2 and you are expecting `imageIndex` = 2, then app will crash bcoz array have 2 count and you trying to access third element....array[2] this will crash

Comment: if your userImages.count = 2 and if you tap on right then  `imageIndex` will be 1 and it will be access `userImages` second element... right?

Comment: Yes, imageIndex needs to be 1 after first tap but nothing happens.

Comment: Okay i did, will share demo with you

Answer (score 0):

I have added gesture on view. When you tap right side index count will increase (left side will decrease), once it reached on array count then it will starts from 0 again.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var userCards = UserCardViewModel() {
        didSet{
            userCards.imageIndexObserver = { index, image in
                //self.showingImage.image = self.userCards.userImages[index]
                print(index)        //<------- Here you will get index
           }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let img1 = UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up.right.video")
        let img2 = UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up.right.video")
        let img3 = UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up.right.video")

        userCards.userImages = [img1!,img2!,img3!]
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func handleTap(_ tapGR: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
         let tapLocation = tapGR.location(in: nil)
         let moveNext = tapLocation.x > self.view.frame.width / 2 ? true : false
         moveNext ? userCards.nextImage() : userCards.previousImage()
     }
}
```

This is Model class

```
struct UserCardViewModel {

    var userImages : [UIImage] = []

    var imageIndex: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            imageIndexObserver?(imageIndex, userImages[imageIndex])
        } }

    var imageIndexObserver: ((Int, UIImage) -> () )?

    mutating func nextImage() {
           imageIndex = imageIndex + 1 >= userImages.count ? 0 : imageIndex + 1
       }

    mutating func previousImage() {
           imageIndex = imageIndex - 1 < 0 ? userImages.count - 1  : imageIndex - 1
       }
}
```

Initially `imageIndex` is `0`

1) At start when you tap on right side `imageIndex` will become 1

2) At start when you tap on left side `imageIndex` will become (yourArray.count - 1)

Download demo from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XqYeQ6xEBJWSGdMR3eiUr_fKnvJ2NngU)

Comment: Your code works, I guess it is all about my structure there is nothing wrong above. Let me clear about that
I have the data in ViewController which initializes ViewModel object in related View with convenience init as I mentioned above. When ViewModel object in related View changes, it triggers didSet{}.